# Crear funciones desde una input en angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, aplicación-web

Estoy creando una app y requiero "crear funciones" desde un textarea, no es nada complejo serian funciones sencillas como enviar un alert o abrir un dialogo. Las funciones serian en typescript pero no he encontrado la manera de realizar esto, obtengo fácilmente el texto con la "función" pero la verdad no se si es posible inyectarlas de algún modo para que sean utilizables.

La verdad es que soy algo nuevo en esto, pero cualquier aporte lo agradezco.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] de paso checa el [tour], te recomiendo editar y mostrar lo que llevas al momento así como derivado de lo anterior tus dudas específicas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues creo que creando un elemento SCRIPT e inyectándole el código sería suficiente.. Te dejo un ejemplo

Espero te ayude,
Un saludo!

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
var code = 'alert("hello world!");';  // Este será tu código del TEXTAREA
try {
   s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
   document.body.appendChild(s);
} catch (e) {
   s.text = code;
   document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

Comment: gracias, funciona perfecto